# When is a character-special file not a character-special file in a Docker container?

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I've been puzzling over a mystery today.  In a Docker container, `find` can think `/dev/console` is a regular file:

```
$ docker run --rm -it almalinux:8
Unable to find image 'almalinux:8' locally
8: Pulling from library/almalinux
6742b8895cef: Already exists
Digest: sha256:7dad5156e6e219e4912623dc28fbe01dd116f0d5bb32cda19b63266201a429bc
Status: Downloaded newer image for almalinux:8
[root@8386577f0000 /]# find / -type f | grep /dev/console
/dev/console
[root@8386577f0000 /]# find /dev/console -type f
[root@8386577f0000 /]# ls -ld /dev/console
crw--w---- 1 root tty 136, 0 Mar 30 14:26 /dev/console
[root@8386577f0000 /]# test -c /dev/console; echo $?
0
[root@8386577f0000 /]# test -f /dev/console; echo $?
1
[root@8386577f0000 /]#
```

I've tried this in various distros (Debian, Ubuntu, CentOS) and they all behave similarly.  It's especially frustrating that the two `find` commands don't work the same with respect to this file.

Is this a bug?  Why does `find` work this way?

Comment: the docker -t creates a Pseudo TTY, that probably is also true for the /dev/console (with major 136). Probably it is a docker issue.